# How to prevent SharedPreferences from loading corrupt data

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have a custom class with 3 `String` fields (`arg1`, `arg2`, `arg3`) and getters/setters. In `Fragment` there are 3 `editText` fields that create a new Object of custom class. And I also have an `ArrayList` of  custom objects (max capacity is 15, but its usualy around 1-3) that is stored in `SharedPreferences`.
Everything worked fine until last update in which I only changed some UI design features in `xml`. Not a single line of Java code was changed, especialy those that have something to do with Custom objects, `ArrayList` or `SharedPrefs`.
Now some users, after updating my app, get corrupted first (or in most cases, only) entry of `ArrayList`, and `arg1` is `""` or `null`. 
The worst thing is they are displayed the value of `arg2` where is explicitly called `textView.setText(arg1)`.
Im saving my `SharedPrefs` in `onStop()` and restoring it in `onCreate()` and I'm using `Gson/Json` for storing. In 99,9% everything is fine, but after recent update, some users reported this problem.

What's going on, and how to prevent it from happening in the future?

EDIT:
What about the fact that I set my `ArrayList` to be `public static`, so I can use it elsewhere, would it be a problem? Also since I can't debug production app, I've noticed that either args or their values have moved like `MyCustomObject("val1", "val2", "val3")` is now  `MyCustomObject("val2", "val3", "???")` I dont know what last value is. Is it `val1` or `""`

Answer (score 1):

> Everything worked fine until last update in which I only changed some
> UI design features in xml.

UI classes (like your custom UI class with 3 EditText) should not be serialized, because UI classes tend to change over time and it is not the pattern. You should only store/serialize data/object that represents UI states, not the UI objects themselves.

> Im saving my SharedPrefs in onStop() and restoring it in onCreate()
> and I'm using Gson/Json for storing. In 99,9% everything is fine, but
> after recent update, some users reported this problem.

Suppose, the newer version of a UI class includes an extra member variable. Now, serializing in the newer version will give a different JSON string than the previous version. And as a result, your UI logic might conflict.

**Workaround**

In this case, you should make ArrayList of *the custom class with 3 String fields (arg1, arg2, arg3) and getters/setters*, then serialize/deserialize this ArrayList with Gson or any other library. Note that, the following example is basic and not perfect since no associated code provided.

In `onCreate()`, initialize the UI components with this data. For example:

```
// Retrieve data and initialize custom data holder by deserializing stored json
CustomObj customObj = gson.get(typeToken, str);
// Use this data to initialize UI components
customUiObj.editText1.setText(customObj.arg1);
customUiObj.editText2.setText(customObj.arg2);
customUiObj.editText3.setText(customObj.arg3);
```

In `onStop()`, retrieve data from the UI components to store. For example:

```
String arg1 = customUiObj.editText1.getText().toString();
String arg2 = customUiObj.editText2.getText().toString();
String arg3 = customUiObj.editText3.getText().toString();
// Now, create a data holder object
CustomObj obj = new CustomObj(arg1, arg2, arg3);
// Serialize this obj
String jsonStr = gson.toJson(customObj);
```

Comment: Thx for answering but, sorry for maybe not being clear enough. My custom class is data class not custom UI class! Nothing about my UI is custom, everything is google/factory style! Data that I'm storing are just user inputed `Strings` like first name, last, title. But then, after update, some users got `firstName.setText(lastNameArg)`.

Comment: Could you please provide your custom class code, that you serialized/deserialized?